# Why does "setf" not work when using "let"?

Tags: variables, reference, common-lisp, variable-assignment, let

The behavior of `setf` when combined with `let` is confusing to me. Here, `setf` isn't changing the second value of my list.

```lisp
(defun to-temp-field (lst)
  (let ((old-value (nth 2 lst))
        (new-value 'hello))
    (progn
      (setf old-value new-value)
      lst)))
```

But if I do it without `let`, it changes ok:

```lisp
(defun to-temp-field (lst)
  (let ((new-value 'hello))
    (progn
      (setf (nth 2 lst) new-value)
      lst)))
```

What's causing this behavior?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you worked in any other programming languages, (e.g., C, Java, Python)? What would your expectations of code like `List<Integer> toTempField(List<Integer> lst) { int oldValue = lst.get(2); int newValue = 4; oldValue = newValue; return lst; }` be? Common Lisp's behavior is the same in this regard.  The thing that Common Lisp lets you do (via `setf` expanders) that many other languages don't, is to write things like `list.get(2) = newValue;` (which is like `(setf (nth 2 lst) new-value)`).  The answers cover this, but I find the explicit comparison helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setf` takes a *[place](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_ab.htm)* and a value, or a number of place/value pairs, and mutates the value of the place to the new value.

In the first code example `old-value` is a lexical variable bound within the `let` form. [Lexical variables are places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aba.htm), so calling `(setf old-value new-value)` sets the value of `old-value` to `new-value`.

[Function forms can also be places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abb.htm), and `nth` is one function that can specify a place. In the second code example calling `(setf (nth 2 lst) new-value)` sets the value of the place `(nth 2 lst)` to the value `new-value`.

So in the first example the place `old-value`, a lexical variable, is updated. But in the second example the form `(nth 2 lst)` is a place, and the object which this form evaluates to (an element of the list `lst`) is updated.

To be clear: a place is not a value, it is a form.

With `(let ((old-value (nth 2 lst)) ;;...))` `old-value` is bound to the *value* to which the form `(nth 2 lst)` evaluates. But with `(setf (nth 2 lst) new-value)` the *form* `(nth 2 lst)` is interpreted as a place. `(setf old-value new-value)` works the same way: `old-value` is a form, and a place. Here the variable `old-value` has been let-bound to the value of the form `(nth 2 lst)`, and it is this value which is replaced via assignment in the call to `setf` by mutating the binding of `old-value`. As a result the value of the place `old-value` has been changed.

A few things to note:

- The second example updates the *third* element of `lst` since lists are zero-indexed in Common Lisp.
- There is no need for the `progn` form inside of `let` since the body of a `let` form is an implicit `progn`.
- Attempting to modify a literal causes undefined behavior in Common Lisp, so you shouldn't call the second function with a quoted list like this: `(to-temp-field '(1 2 3))` or with a variable bound to a list literal, but rather like this: `(to-temp-field (list 1 2 3))` or with a variable bound to a list that has been otherwise constructed.

Comment: For anyone reading this question in future this is probably the answer which should have been accepted.

Comment: "Here `old-value` has been let-bound to the value of the form `(nth 2 lst)`, and it is this value (object) which is updated by setf" seems to be wrong. The value ie "object (nth 2 lst)" is not updated. The *variable* `old-value`  is updated ie its old value is forgotten and it is assigned  a new value.

Comment: @WillNess -- Hmm. The HyperSpec says: [The value of a place is the object to which the place form evaluates. The value of a place can be changed by using setf.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aa.htm) I thought that I was following the language of the spec more-or-less, but I wrote that the value is "updated" instead of "changed". I have added a bit in an attempt to clarify, but I'm not sure that was successful ;)

Comment: If the value/object `(nth 2 lst)` were being updated/changed, `lst` would change as well. In `(let ((a B)) ...`, B is not used as a place. `(nth ...)` form *can* be used as a place (if appearing as 1st arg to setf, is my understanding), but isn't, there. In `(setf v ...)`, `v` is a lex var, and changing it just means setting the var's value, forgetting the previous one. Is my understanding.

Comment: @WillNess -- I'm not sure I understand your comment. With `(setf v ...)` `v` is a place which [may name a lexical variable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aba.htm). In that case `v` is updated as if by `(setq v ...)` which assigns a new value to `v`, as you say. IAC, I have tried to tighten that part of my answer a bit.

Comment: it is better now, but still, you write 1. "the variable `old-value` has been let-bound to the value of the form `(nth 2 lst)`, and it is this value which is updated by `setf`" and I say, `setf` couldn't be bothered with this value, all it sees is `old-value` which it just sets to a new value; and 2. "in `(setf old-value new-value)`, `old-value` is a place associated with the value resulting from `(nth 2 lst)`" and I say, `old-value` is a place associated with the *binding* named by `old-value`, and it is that binding that is updated by `setf`. in both cases, ...

Comment: ... in both cases the place associated with a lexical variable is its *binding*, and its prior value is irrelevant. That's my perspective here. :)

Comment: @WillNess -- _"the place associated with a lexical variable is its binding"_ is not what the spec says; it says that a place is a form, and this is what I was trying to emphasize above.

Comment: well, CLHS says that a "place n. [[is]] 1. a form which is suitable for use as a generalized reference. [[or]] 2. *the conceptual location* [[emph mine]] referred to by such a form[1]." a value is put into a location. for a variable, that's what in Scheme we'd call "binding". *the variable's* [having a] value is what's being updated, not the variable's [previous] *value*. bringing up the previous value in this context is confusing because it might create an impression that that previous value is being updated when in fact it is simply discarded. that's all I'm saying.

Comment: "binding" not just in Scheme, in CL as well: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_b.htm#binding.

Comment: @WillNess -- it wasn't clear to me that the spec _requires_ `setf` to mutate bindings in the case of `(setf v new-v)` due to _"...all that is guaranteed is that ... the ultimate result of evaluating `setf` is the value or values being stored."_ But after looking through the spec some more it seems pretty clear that "being stored" means assignment, and assignment always mutates bindings. I have updated the answer; let me know if you see anything still in need of attention.

Comment: will do. isn't CLHS *fun*? (and not cryptic at all)  /:$ #$%^#@&^!( O8-L  :)

Answer (score 4):

Your first snippet works like this:

```
(defun to-temp-field (l)
```

`L` is a variable, supposed to have a list as its value

```
    (let ((old-value (nth 2 l))
```

`OLD-VALUE` is a variable and is initialized to the third element of the list `L`

```
          (new-value 'hello))
```

`NEW-VALUE` is a variable and is initialized to the symbol `HELLO`

```
        (setf old-value new-value)
```

the variable `OLD-VALUE` is set to the value of the variable `NEW-VALUE` -> `HELLO`

```
        l))
```

`L` is returned, unchanged.

The second snippet works like this:

```
(defun to-temp-field (l)
```

`L` is a variable, supposed to have a list as its value

```
    (let ((new-value 'hello))
```

`NEW-VALUE` is a variable and is initialized to the symbol `HELLO`

```
        (setf (nth 2 l) new-value)
```

`SETF` changes the place `(NTH 2 L)` to the value of the variable `NEW-VALUE`. This place denotes the third element of the list `L`. The list is changed, it now has the symbol `HELLO` as its third element.

```
        l))
```

L is returned, changed.

Comment: I think it'd be better to have those explanations as part of the text, not of code. Screens are narrow on phones. :)

Comment: I've edited, so it's easier to read on phones. hope it's OK.

Comment: @WillNess: are people really reading stackoverflow on phones?

Comment: I did. :) (I edited on a computer though).

Comment: @WillNess: I gave up, because code snippets in Stackoverflow are in most cases wider than what my phone can display in landscape.

Comment: I didn't even know there were comments in your answer until I flipped the phone to landscape. that's the reason for this. :)

Comment: @Will Ness: I'm not sure about the usability of the comment version I used. The new version is (for me) not optimal on a larger screen, because I find it difficult to follow, because the reading flow of the code is interrupted multiple times. If somebody comes up with a better idea how to explain/annotate each line of code, I would be interested.

Comment: perhaps increasing the indentation levels would help, say incrementing by 3 or 4 chars each time? because the vertical alignment *is* preserved here. I've edited, is it better?

Answer (score 0):

`setf` is a macro that, simply put, understands what is being set and calls the corresponding set based on that, so `(setf old-value new value)` simply sets the value, whereas in the second case it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`setf` is a macro and does completely different things when the first argument is a symbol than some accessor for a list structure.

It's very easy to see that when you are supplying a symbol it does something completely different than if you supply the `nth` form:

```
> (get-setf-expansion '(setf (nth 2 lst) new-value))
(#:TEMP-2859 #:TEMP-2858 #:TEMP-2857) ;
(2 LST NEW-VALUE) ;
(#:NEW-2856) ;
(FUNCALL #'(SETF SYSTEM::%SETNTH) #:NEW-2856 #:TEMP-2859 #:TEMP-2858 #:TEMP-2857) ;
(SYSTEM::%SETNTH #:TEMP-2859 #:TEMP-2858 #:TEMP-2857)

>  (macroexpand-1 '(setf (nth 2 lst) new-value))
(SYSTEM::%SETNTH 2 LST NEW-VALUE) ;
T
```

Last line you see it calls internal function `%setnth`. This is implementation specific so SBCL does does something else. However; This is clearly fetching the place and doing the same as `(rplaca (cddr lst) new-value)` while when you cached the value from `(nth 2 lst)` to `old-value`:

```
$(get-setf-expansion '(setf old-value 99))
(#:TEMP-3005 #:TEMP-3004) ;
(OLD-VALUE 99) ;
(#:NEW-3003) ;
(FUNCALL #'(SETF SETQ) #:NEW-3003 #:TEMP-3005 #:TEMP-3004) ;
(SETQ #:TEMP-3005 #:TEMP-3004)

> (macroexpand-1 '(setf old-value 99))
(SETQ OLD-VALUE 99) ;
T
```

This does a `setq` so it will just rebind the local variable `old-value` to point to `99`. You cannot cache old-place since the macro won't understand it anymore.

Answer (score -3):

Common Lisp is one of the earliest languages to exhibit [call-by-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), a paradigm that's now extremely common in dynamically-typed and higher-level programming languages. In a call-by-sharing language, values bound to a variable implicitly undergo a sort of shallow copy, taking a new version of the uppermost pointer or data but leaving any nested data identical.

In a Lisp, this distinction is actually easier to see. The top-level cons cell is copied, but any nested pointers are left alone.

```
(defun to-temp-field (lst)
  (let ((old-value (nth 2 lst))
        (new-value 'hello))
    (progn
      (setf old-value new-value)
      lst)))
```

Here, `old-value` is *not* a reference to a position in the list. It's a shallow copy of the value at position 2 of the list. As indicated in khachik's answer, `setf` is actually just a really complicated macro, and macros dispatch their behavior of the *syntax* they see. So what `setf` sees as its first argument is `old-value`. This is happening at compile time, so `setf` has no way to know that `old-value` came from a list, or from an `nth` call, so it just sets the local variable (using basically [`setq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_setq.htm)).

Now, consider your second example,

```
(defun to-temp-field (lst)
  (let ((new-value 'hello))
    (progn
      (setf (nth 2 lst) new-value)
      lst)))
```

Here, `setf` sees `(nth 2 lst)` as its first argument. This is *not* a local variable. This is actually a function-call-like expression. And as we can see in the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_nth.htm), `nth` actually has two entries: one for a normal function call and one for when it's used in `setf`. That's because, just like we can define normal functions as

```
(defun nth (n lst)
  ...)
```

We can separately define a `setf` accessor as

```
(defun (setf nth) (n lst)
  ...)
```

That's not pseudocode. `defun` actually accepts `(setf whatever)` as a valid declared function name, and when you use `setf` on a function call, the macro looks for a function with this name.

Comment: "The top-level cons cell is copied" -> I don't understand that. Where is what cons-cell copied?

Comment: There is so much wrong with this answer it is hard to know where to start.  No cons cell is copied.  Common Lisp is not one of the earliest languages to do this.

Comment: you write near the top: "`old-value` is *not* a reference to a position in the list. It's a shallow copy of the value at position 2 of the list" and this can't possibly be correct, because with `(setf (car old-value) new-value)`, calling `(to-temp-field (list 0 1 (list 2 2) 3))` returns
`(0 1 (HELLO 2) 3)`. so it emphatically ***is*** a reference to a position in the list. if it were a shallow copy, only the deeper references like e.g. `(setf (caar old-value) new-value)` would update the `lst` structure. so no, it is ***not*** a shallow copy of that value, it is a copy of a *pointer* to it.